# Is it always necessary to add to the possessive when saying I made something with my "own" hands?

Tags: grammar

It only seems to add emphasis, and therefore seems redundant. So, what's wrong with "I made this with my hands"?

Comment: As opposed to making it with your feet?

Comment: "own hands" is emphasis but that doesn't mean it's redundant. It serves the purpose of being emphatic. In contrast "with my hands" sounds more redundant as it doesn't carry the same emphasis.

Comment: It might depend on what you're making: some things can only be made with your hands, others can be made by machine or internet service.

Comment: it would be more usual to say “I made this myself,” distinguishing it from something bought or made by someone else.

Comment: Or just to say it is hand-made rather than factory-produced.

Comment: What research have you done? Google ngrams, e.g., is an easy place to find some usage statistics.

Comment: MarcinManhattan - Granted, I actually adapted this question to fit a different but related problem I had, i.e. "..she hung in the cotton and jute sacs of the macramé plant hangers she had, in some cases, only just fashioned with her hands" for the life of me it not seeming necessary to abide by the usual form of the idiom. Anyway, here's an example where in the title the writer didn't. https://brainly.com/question/25743987

Comment: Can you Post some wider examples? 

'My…' or 'my own…' hands seem interchangeable yet isn't 'my hands' merely a statement of fact, to be compared to 'my hammer/saw/screwdriver/sickle…'?

On the other hand doesn't 'with my own hands' clearly express pride?

Comment: It clearly does express pride. So this is 'perhaps' why I'm hesitant to use it in the above example, as my character takes her creative nous and manual dexterity strictly for granted. But, of course, I can't speak for Amy Ludwig. https://theclassroombookshelf.com/2018/05/07/with-my-hands-poems-about-making-things/